# file download with php (working on apache under localhost)

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I'm trying to create a file download page. This page when requested should prompt the user to download a file. Here is the source code for the page:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=zip.zip')

header('Content-type: application/zip');

readfile('zip.zip');

?>
```

This works ok.

The problems starts when I want to move the file `zip.zip` from the folder where this script is in. I tried using relative and absolute URLs but I always get strange results,
the browser still prompts for file download but somehow it's just an odd file name converted from the URI I supplied somthing like "`.._.._files_zip.zip` instead of `../../files/zip.zip`.

Any suggestions why this happens?
Thanks

Comment: Post an example of something that doesn't work

Comment: <?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=./zip.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile('./zip.zip');
?>
even when trying to fetch the file from same place using relative url like the code posted in this comment it's not working resulting in downloading file named "_zip.zip" which doesn't really exist
thanks for the intrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://docs.php.net/basename) to get just the file name:

```
$file = '../../files/zip.zip';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
readfile($file);
```

Comment: thanks for this :)
this worked it out
highly appreciate the help